# React Vite + SockJS Client All transports failed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sockjs

My project using react + vite without any proxy config
Im trying to use webstomp-client and sockjs to connect to websocket server (Springboot support SockJS)

The backend springboot server generated by JHipster and have default config for websocket like below:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.config;

import com.mycompany.myapp.security.AuthoritiesConstants;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.server.*;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.socket.server.HandshakeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.DefaultHandshakeHandler;
import tech.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    public static final String IP_ADDRESS = "IP_ADDRESS";

    private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    public WebsocketConfiguration(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
        this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        String[] allowedOrigins = Optional
            .ofNullable(jHipsterProperties.getCors().getAllowedOrigins())
            .map(origins -> origins.toArray(new String[0]))
            .orElse(new String[0]);
        registry
            .addEndpoint("/websocket/tracker")
            .setHandshakeHandler(defaultHandshakeHandler())
            .setAllowedOrigins(allowedOrigins)
            .withSockJS()
            .setInterceptors(httpSessionHandshakeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public HandshakeInterceptor httpSessionHandshakeInterceptor() {
        return new HandshakeInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public boolean beforeHandshake(
                ServerHttpRequest request,
                ServerHttpResponse response,
                WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                Map<String, Object> attributes
            ) throws Exception {
                if (request instanceof ServletServerHttpRequest) {
                    ServletServerHttpRequest servletRequest = (ServletServerHttpRequest) request;
                    attributes.put(IP_ADDRESS, servletRequest.getRemoteAddress());
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void afterHandshake(
                ServerHttpRequest request,
                ServerHttpResponse response,
                WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                Exception exception
            ) {}
        };
    }

    private DefaultHandshakeHandler defaultHandshakeHandler() {
        return new DefaultHandshakeHandler() {
            @Override
            protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) {
                Principal principal = request.getPrincipal();
                if (principal == null) {
                    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ANONYMOUS));
                    principal = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken("WebsocketConfiguration", "anonymous", authorities);
                }
                return principal;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In client side (React app), im trying to connect to /websocket/tracker registered above like this

```
const url = `${WS_URL}/websocket/tracker?access_token=${authToken}`
  const socket = new SockJS(url)
  const stompClient = Stomp.over(
    socket, { protocols: ['v12.stomp'] }
  )
  stompClient.connect({}, (f) => {
    console.log('Connection established', f)
  }, (e) => {
    console.error('Connect failed', e)
  })
```

But even when i use springboot server or public test websocket server (https://stream.elite12.de/api/sock) (I mean this may not server config issue), the above client code give me error code 2000: All transport failed
image

Anyone have encountered this? Please give me an advice.

Node: 20.6.1
sockjs-client: 1.6.1
webstomp-client: 1.2.6
React project template: Metronic v8.0.25

I've tried switch to other browser (firefox, chrome, safari) but nothing changed, i also tried to debug into sockjs-client source code and found that all availableTransports can't enable (All driver undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason no transport available for enable is integrate SockJS into react app cause `global is not defined`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
at Object../node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/utils/browser-crypto.js (browser-crypto.js:3)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
at Object../node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/utils/random.js (random.js:4)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
at Object../node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/utils/event.js (event.js:3)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
at Object../node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/transport/websocket.js (websocket.js:3)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
at Object../node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/transport-list.js (transport-list.js:5)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
```

Instead of declare global variable, i have define in vite `defineConfig` as `{}`
The correct fix is declare global variable in index.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).